# Dispose submit button with ajax-jquery and php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code, for learning porpose. In short, I want to grab some data from a database, with the help of a drop-down menu. My problem is that now I'm using a submit button to make the submit action. And the improvement that I want, is to get rid of the submit button, and grab the infos when the drop-down changes.

I've tried to make a function for the code between line 1 and 12, and call it with: `<body onload="process()">`, but it's not working. Then I tried to put the `onchange="this.form.submit()"` attribute to the `<select>` element, but this doesn't work also, because it sends the data to process.php like any normal submission when not using ajax.
Anyone know any fix? Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="viewdata()">
    <form action="process.php" method="post" id="form">
        <select name="select" id="select">
            <option value="">Choose</option>
            <option value="1">supervizor</option>
            <option value="2">sef locatie</option>
            <option value="3">muncitor</option>
            <option value="0">toti</option>
        </select><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#form'); // **LINE 1**
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#show').html(data);
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });                    // **LINE 12**

    function viewdata(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "process.php"
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $('#show').html(data);
        });
    }
    </script>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="show"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is you method `process()>` ?

Comment: I already mention it: the js process() function consists of the code between line 1 and 12. But here I posted the original code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind your processing on the change event of your drop down box.

```
$("#select").on("change", function(ev) {
    // Your ajax processing
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#show').html(data);
        }
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Tried your method, but it's redirecting to the process.php script, and it's not what I want...

Comment: @DanCostinel, Do not submit the form. Just run the ajax there. See update